# constructing vectors from arrays

Tags: c++, stdvector

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) states I can construct a vector from an array as follows:

```
// the iterator constructor can be used to construct from arrays:
int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
vector<int> myvector (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

Why is the constructor's second argument `myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression  `sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)` gets the number of elements in the `myints` array.

`myints` gets a pointer to the first element of the array.

So the expression `myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)` is a pointer one past the end of the `myints` array, which is what the [two-iterator constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) expects. This creates a vector with a copy of all the elements in the original array.

Bear in mind that pointers are iterators, so the above is equivalent to

```
vector<int> myvector (std::begin(myints), std::end(myint));
```

Comment: Why must we divide `sizeof(myints)` by `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: @E.Kaufman to get the number of ints. `sizeof` gives the number of bytes of a thing. If the thing is an array, it will be the size of the array in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It gets pointer to an **int** after last element. So it becomes like begin() and end()

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)
```

is the number of elements in the array.

```
myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int)
```

gives you the memory location that is one past the end of your array.

STL uses iterators for the first element and one-past-the-end to specify a range. The vector constructor is using such a range.